# Logical difference between LINQ Where() and FirstOrDefault()

Tags: c#, linq

I know this may sound duplicate question (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998437/and-difference-between-firstordefaultfunc-wherefunc-firstordefault) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842794/wherecondition-firstordefault-vs-firstordefaultcondition) ) but I wanted some clarity regarding the number iterations that will take place in this query.

My assumptions are as follows:

lets say I have collection of 1000 items.

1. In Where() query, it iterates through each and every item and add it to IEnumerable. i.e. it will need O(n) always.

   ```
   foreach (var item in myList)
   {
       if(//<condition>)
       {
           //add it to list/enumerable
       }
       //continue through entire list
   }
   ```
2. In `FirstOrDefault(<condition>)` query,it starts iterating through the collection and breaks the loop as soon as it gets the item matching the `<condition>` and returns single element or only if no item is matching `<condition>` then it will iterate through entire list.

so complexity can be from O(1) to O(n)

```
foreach (var item in myList)
{
    if(//<condition>)
    {
        //return item
        break;
    }
}
```

if this is correct then it will always be better to use FirstORDefault for a single item return.?

Comment: Big-O is expressed as the worst case scenario. `FirstOrDefault()` will be 0(n).

Comment: For a single item return, you should use `FirstOrDefault` (or similar methods, e.g. `Single`), not `Where`, because that's what it best expresses. Whether it's faster than some other implementation is another question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Where` is actually deferred - i.e. it does not have any cost until the enumeration happens.

`Where` looks kind of like this, and returns a new `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
foreach (var item in enumerable)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

`FirstOrDefault` returns `T`.

Comment: Wow.I didn't know this deferred thing. Thanks for clearing doubt.

Comment: @deathrace when you see a standard linq operation return `IEnumerable<T>` (or one of its derived forms), it is a deferred result.

Comment: @DanielA.White What would be better approach if we are dealing with IQueryable, I assume that `Where()` would be a good option as it will apply filter on datasource. Is it correct?

Comment: @Ummar it depends on the query provider.

Comment: @DanielA.White I am working in LINQ to SQL. any idea about its internal working?

Answer (score 2):

`FirstOrDefault` will stop checking (i.e. break) when/if it finds anything.

edit:
However, as Daniel pointed out, `Where` is deferred, so you can also stop iterating yourself and it will have the same performance as `FirstOrDefault` (although then you might as well just use `FirstOrDefault)`

Comment: The point of the question is the OP thinks that `Where()` will fully enumerate the list before passed on to `FirstOrDefault`. Which means his assumption is incorrect, not correct.

Answer (score 2):

`FirstOrDefault` enumerates the query while `Where` just returns a new enumerator. Below statements give the same results:

```
var result = coll.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
var result = coll.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: If I want to find the result then which one is better?